# Inverse function theorem via degree theory

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems, inverse-function-theorem

In [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/75049/69037) Terrence Tao writes the following about the inverse function theorem.

> The Brouwer fixed point theorem gives local surjectivity, and degree theory gives local injectivity if $\det Df(x_0)$ never changes sign. (This gives another proof in the case when $f$ is continuously differentiable, since $\det Df$ is then continuous.)

I am not familiar with degree theory, so I cannot fill in the gaps here.

1. How *exactly* does degree theory give locally injectivity if $\det
       Df(x_0)$ never changes sign?
2. How *exactly* does the Brouwer fixed point theorem give local surjectivity?

Comment: here is Tao explaining how the brouwer fixed point theorem implies "invariance of domain" i.e. Item 2 https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/